# Reflections visible in Vieweport but Flat/Barely noticeable in final render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, hdri, reflection

I'm having trouble rendering this scene I've made from Grant Abbitt's steampunk goggles tutorial. The thing is when I'm looking through the Viewport I can clearly see reflections from the material, but then when I go to render, the reflections look flat or barely visible.

[Link to .blend file with packed textures](http://www.mediafire.com/file/5qun1p58s509hr8/BlenderFileReflections.blend/file)

Screenshots:
[image: Here's how it looks in the Viewport]
[image: Here's how it looks in the final render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene environment is not set up properly. The HDRI is using an ordinary Image Texture node, not an Environment Texture node:

[image]

Deleting it and replacing it with an Environment Texture node fixes the render:

[image]

The reason the result looks okay in the 3D viewport is because it looks like you had Scene World unchecked in the scene options:

[image]

If you check that box, then the 3D viewport matches the rendered result.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick :D